# Perform segue from onboarding / tutorial screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

I am using the `UIPageViewController` for an on boarding / tutorial screen, and my problem is as follows:

When the user is on the last page of the tutorial, i want a left swipe gesture not to try and swipe the page controller, but instead to perform a segue to the registration page. I threw a print statement into the `viewDidLoad` in the `UIViewController` for the last page of the tutorial, and it registers.

In that same `viewDidLoad` I create my gestures to perform the segue, but nothing happens. I even tried putting the `performSegue` inside of the viewDidLoad, but nothing happened. I have my segue connected to the `UIPageViewController` as well as my `GrowController`, and neither register. I'm at a loss!

This is the `UIViewController` for the last page of tutorial

```
class GrowController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("*********************************")
    createGesture()
    // performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowRegister", sender: self)
}


func createGesture() {
    let showReg = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showRegister))
    showReg.direction = .left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(showReg)
}


func showRegister(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showRegister", sender: self)
}

}
```

This is the `UIPageViewController` that handles the tutorial logic

```
class TutorialViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var viewControllerIndex: Int?

lazy var tutorialArray: [UIViewController] = {
    return [self.tutorialInstance(name: "page1"), self.tutorialInstance(name: "page2"), self.tutorialInstance(name: "page3")]
}()


private func tutorialInstance(name: String?) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name!)
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let image = UIImage(named: "export.png") {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: image)
    } else {
        print("Error")
    }

    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self

    if let firstViewController = tutorialArray.first {
        setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

These are the delgate and datasource functions

```
// Page View Controller delegate functions
public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = tutorialArray.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            return nil
    }

    guard tutorialArray.count > previousIndex else {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowRegister", sender: self)  // Added this line just testng around, nothing happend here though.
        return nil
    }

    return tutorialArray[previousIndex]
}


public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = tutorialArray.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

    guard nextIndex < tutorialArray.count else {
        return nil
    }

    guard tutorialArray.count > nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return tutorialArray[nextIndex]
}

public func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return tutorialArray.count
}

public func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first, let firstViewControllerIndex = tutorialArray.index(of: firstViewController) else {
        return 0
    }
    return firstViewControllerIndex
}
```

Lots of code for what is probably a simple answer.

tl;dr - How can I make a swipe gesture perform a segue from a specific page of the `UIPageViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a delegate method that you can implement  [pageViewController(_:willTransitionTo:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdelegate/1614091-pageviewcontroller) but I don't know that its worth the trouble.  Maybe just put another view in front of it and put a swipe gesture recognizer view in that view and use the gesture recognized to manually change the page or segue to the new controller.

Comment: Ahhh thank you, willTransitionTo: will most likely do it for me! But I want to try it the way you mentioned by adding a view on top - I added a subview into my GrowController to cover the whole view and added the gesture to it, but now as soon as I swipe to the GrowController, the app crashes. Will post picture of errors soon when I'm looking at my code again

Comment: here is my error [Error](https://i.imgsafe.org/44128d39bf.png).

and i added `@IBOutlet weak var swipeView: UIView!` to my code, and it crashes upon loading.

Comment: Your error says the class is not key value compliant for swipeView.  This is almost always the result of deleting an outlet in code but not in the story board.  Right click on the yellow view controller icon in the storyboard and it will show all of the outlets.  The outlet with the yellow triangle on it is the one that has no corresponding outlet int he view controller; delete it.

Comment: Ya that's the first thing I thought, double/triple checked all my outlets and were good, so im really not sure what it could be at this point.